# How to use foreign key as a distinct value and sort the queryset with a timestamp field first in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am using Postgres in my django project and I want to get all the tickets based on a customer full_name search with distinct customer_id and sort the ticket queryset based on card_timestamp field in Ticket model.

I have two models like the following:

```
class Ticket(BaseTimeClass, BaseDeletedClass):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
related_name="generated_tickets")
    is_replied = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_resolved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    card_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Customer(BaseDeletedClass):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="")
```

I have tried with this:

```
Ticket.objects.filter(Q(customer__full_name__icontains="shuvo"))
            .select_related("customer")
        .order_by("customer_id", "-card_timestamp")
        .distinct("customer_id")
        )
```

the problem with this query is, it is returning the queryset sorted by the customer_id 1st then using the card_timestamp. for better scenario, e.g. there can be multiple customer named with "shuvo":  customer_id can be 1870, 1120, 3210, and their card_timestamp value is "13 january 2023", "28 december 2022" and "14 december 2022". expected scenario, the queryset should return customer_id 1870, 1120 and 3210 sequentially but it is returning customer_id 3210,1870, 1120. how to solve this problem using django-orm? thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you order by customer_id if you want to order by card_timestamp. I am not sure to understand what you want to do

Comment: if I don't use customer_id in order_by initial expression it will throw an error like this "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions" @LucasGrugru

Comment: yes, but the call to distinct is useless too i think

Comment: And if you think you need to call distinct, you can set customer_id in second argument of ordering instead of set in first position

Comment: the same customer_id can have multiple tickets. So I need distinct.
putting customer_id in the second argument throws the same error as well.

Comment: If you want all tickets based on a full name search, i don't see the point of your distinct. If the user of id 1 has 3 tickets you should return all of those

Comment: A customer can create 100 tickets. If I show the admin only the latest one with the distinct customers he will find the other ticket references. For your reference, this is a chat inbox-based ticketing system. So showing all the tickets of a customer does not make any sense. The search box will be flooded.